# Java for/while loop for unique integer

Tags: java

Need help figuring out what's wrong with my code. I am taking a
 beginning java course so I have to use simple code.

> an integer N is unique if there exists an integer i such that: N = i*i
>   + i Here are some examples of unique numbers: 2 (because 2 = 1*1 + 1) 6 (because 6 = 2*2 + 2) 12 (because 12 = 3*3 + 3)
>
> Asks the user to enter an integer N. Prints out whether that number is
>   a unique number. If not print not a unique number

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class task4 {

    /**
* @param args the command line arguments
*/
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.printf("Enter an integer N: ");
        int N = in.nextInt();
        boolean unique = true;
        int i = 1;
        while ((i*i)+i == N)
        {
            if ((i*i)+i != N) 
            {
                unique = false;


                i++;
            }
        }
        if (unique)
        {
            System.out.printf("%d is unique.\n",N);
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.printf("%d is not unique.\n", N);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your code do? What doesn't it do? What steps have you taken to debug it? Also, please remember, that when you post your code for others to review, try to understand and help you with, it pays for you to put in effort to format your code well, and regretfully, yours is not with a lot of code flush left. Please take time now to re-format your code so that it is presentable, so that all code blocks are indented the same amount.

Comment: I know you are a beginner, but we always had to look at our code - we didn't have S.O. to find typos. `while ((i*i)+i == N)  {   if ((i*i)+i != N)` is just nonsense. You only get into the loop if the condition is met, and then the first thing you do is say "if the same condition is not met"

Comment: You could make it a lot easier if you realize that `i*i+i` is `(i+1)*i`. So your `n` falls between two squares, `i^2` and `(i+1)^2`. Given `int n = ... some number ...;`, you can do `int i = (int) Math.sqrt(n); boolean unique = (i * i + i == n);` You don't need a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be of some hlep to you. Check for `i` should always be lesser than `N` in the while loop. At least it has got some exit condition (which is logical). In your case there is no exit condition out of while loop when your `(i*i)+i` grows beyond N.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Task4 {

    /**
* @param args the command line arguments
*/
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.printf("Enter an integer N: ");
        int N = in.nextInt();
        boolean unique = false;
        int i = 1;
        while (((i*i)+i) <= N)
        {
            if ((i*i)+i != N) {
                i++;
            } else {
                unique = true;
                break;
            }
        }    
        if (unique)
        {
            System.out.printf("%d is unique.\n",N);

        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.printf("%d is not unique.\n", N);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop will only evaluate if `1*1 + 1 == N` is true. I don't want to give you the answer directly so I will give you a hint: how can you change the while loop to return true for every value up to N?

Also try redoing the inside of the `while` loop. Think about how you can make it to make `unique` `true` if any value of `i` is valid.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment?

Comment: Should it? I can change it but I feel like it's useful enough to the OP to post as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I am re doing it now

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class task4 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.printf("Enter an integer N: ");
    int N = in.nextInt();
    boolean unique = true;
    double sd = Math.sqrt(N);
    double fd = Math.floor(sd);
    if(sd * (sd+1) != N){
        unique = false;
    }
    if (unique)
    {
        System.out.printf("%d is unique.\n",N);
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.printf("%d is not unique.\n", N);
    }
}
```

}